# How to prove the inverse map is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I try to find an example of the condition in Banach open mapping theorem of "completeness" is necessary. I consider the identity map $T$ from $X=(C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ to $Y=(C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_1)$. Clearly, $X$ is complete but $Y$ is not.

I try to show that $T$ is bounded but the inverse map $T^{-1}$ is not bounded. Clearly, $T$ is a bijection.

Since
$$
\|Tf\|_{1}=\int_0^1 |f|\le \|f\|_{\infty},
$$
then
$$
\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|_1\le 1}\|Tf\|_{1}\le 1
$$

But for the inverse map $T^{-1}$,
$$
\|T^{-1}(f)\|_{\infty}=\|f\|_{\infty}=\operatorname{esssup}|f|
$$

How do we prove that $\|T^{-1}\|$ is not bounded? I try to find some examples. If we take $f(x)=x\in L_1$. Then
$$
\|T^{-1}(f)\|_{\infty}=\|f\|_{\infty}=\operatorname{esssup}|f|=1
$$
So it does not work...

Comment: You need to be a smidgeon more creative writing down functions with integral $1$.

Comment: MathJax tip: you can create your own operators using the `\operatorname{}` command in MathJax/Latex. Note the difference between $esssup|f|$ and $\operatorname{esssup}|f|$, produced by `esssup|f|` and `\operatorname{esssup}|f|` respectively. You can also consider using `\operatorname*{}` to get an operator in the style of $\lim$. For example,$$\operatorname*{esssup}_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$$is produced by `$$\operatorname*{esssup}_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$$`.

Comment: I'd say `\operatorname{ess\,sup}` etc. to add a small space between ess and sup.

Comment: Just look at the functions $x^{n}$

Comment: You want sequence of functions which take higher and higher max values and yet the integral is bounded. Let's say for simplicity you want your maximum value at $0$. So for each $n$ think of function that starts at $n$ for $x = 0$ but decreases rapidly so the integral is bounded (let's say $1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try for example functions that start with $y = n$ at $x = 0$ and drop quickly to $y = 0$ at $x = 1/n$. The integrals will be bounded even though the maximum values will not be.

Comment: Much simpler: $x^{n} \to 0$ in $L^{1}$ norm but not in $L^{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: I didn't know that's done repeatedly by the OP.